# SQL Server 2012: Change a Master List return value, to a different return value that already exists.

Tags: merge, sql-server-2012

I have the following entries in my database:

```
employer_id                             name
69AB90AE-F172-4A84-BB35-8553674E3905    None5
34850FE7-5E7F-4E39-9FD6-9F88EF7075FE    None
```

What are the commands to change the `69AB90AE-F172-4A84-BB35-8553674E3905 None5` to become 
`34850FE7-5E7F-4E39-9FD6-9F88EF7075FE None` and rid of the None5?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
UPDATE table SET guidCol = CAST(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '" GUID varchar "') where your condtion
```